# time zone issue for tweets and scheduled task

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, cron

I am working in a site which will allow to post to twitter and facebook. The reply/comments to the particular post from twitter/facebook can be replied from our site. This works fine.

I used to show the daily, weekly, monthly statistic of each post . This is done by running cron at the end of day. Cron used to update the db with daily posted comments/tweets .

Now the problem arise, my client is some where in EST time zone. Time difference between me and my client is approximately 5 hrs . so my scheduled task(cron) works before the clients end of day.So the comments/tweets posted by him will not be updated in my db. Therefore the statistics is not getting updated.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Why don't you just run the cron job at the end of the day in your clients time zone? At midnight in your client's timezone, run it at 5:00am your time?

Comment: @StevenV thanks for reply.. For example consider two users where both are in different time zone. Now if I run cron according to one users time zone then the tweets posted by other users may not get updated..